# How to create one mat-table per row of a datasource

Tags: angular, angular-material

I know how to create a mat-table with one line per datasource record.

Like this:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="groups">  

    <ng-container matColumnDef="group">
         <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Group</mat-header-cell>
         <mat-cell *matCellDef="let group">{{ group.name }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>  

    <ng-container matColumnDef="year1">
         <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Year 1</mat-header-cell>
         <mat-cell *matCellDef="let group">{{ group.year1 }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>  

    <ng-container matColumnDef="year2">
         <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Year 2</mat-header-cell>
         <mat-cell *matCellDef="let group">{{ group.year2 }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>  

    <ng-container matColumnDef="year3">
         <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Year 3</mat-header-cell>
         <mat-cell *matCellDef="let group">{{ group.year3 }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>  

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

This will produce a table like this:

[image: single mat table]

But instead of having one group per row, I'd like to have one new mat-table per group.

And then, have group data inside each group mat-table.

Like this:

[image: one mat-table per datasource row]

So, how to create a new mat-table per row of the datasource?

Thanks.